# reducing temperature of drinking water from 10c to 5c in 90sec using Peltier module. I have no background in physics so please talk simply

Tags: peltier, cooling, water

Right straight up I have no background in physics.
I need to cool drinking water 1000ml in 90 seconds.  I would like to cool the water to approximately 5c +/- 1c.  The temperature of the water before cooling is 13c.  I would like to use Peltier modules (PM).

Questions: 
1. Is it possible?
2. What do you suggest?
3. What electrical draw would your suggestion require in watts?
4. How would you draw the heat away from the PM?
5. Could the cooling be achieved with a series of PM one after another?
6. The input tube will be either 1/4" or 1/2"

With respect Please don't waste your time telling me about compressors as I know them.

I look forward to hearing your answers and suggestions by email.

Thank you in advance

Ben Hodges

.

Answer (score 6):

**1. Is it possible?**

Sure. Easy, no. Worthwhile, probably not.

**2. What do you suggest?**

You've already stated that you want to use a TEC, so I'm not entirely sure what the question is.

**3. What electrical draw would your suggestion require in watts?**

Now we start to get into the meat. As a matter of nomenclature, the Peltier module in such application is generally called a TEC (ThermoElectric Cooler). The first thing you need to know is the energy required to heat or cool water is called the specific heat of water. You should look it up. For liquid water, it's a bit more than 4 joules per gram per degree. Your 1000 ml of water weighs 1000 grams, so you'll need 4000 joules per degree of cooling. Rounding your start temperature to 15 C, you'll need a 10 degree drop, so that works out to 40,000 joules. Providing this over 90 seconds requires 40,000/90, or about 440 watts of cooling. Let's call it 400, since the specific heat was rounded down.

Now, TECs have a rule of thumb - you can generally get about 10% efficiency. This means that you'll need about 4000 watts of power applied to your TECs. That is a whole lot of power - as an example, a standard circuit breaker for household current is 15 amps. At 120 VAC, thats 15 x 120, or 1800 watts. So you'd need the equivalent of more than two full-sized electric heaters worth of electricity.

**4. How would you draw the heat away from the PM?**

That is usually done either with heat-dissipating fins or a liquid (usually water) cooling system. Note that if you're talking about 60 W modules, you'll need about 67 of them, so you're going to need a lot of tubing.

**5. Could the cooling be achieved with a series of PM one after another?**

It can, but it's not an applicable idea. TECs are limited to a certain hot/cold temperature drop, and the smaller the better. 10 degrees is a perfectly good design goal, and it allows for good efficiency. Layered TECs are used to provide large temperature differences, not good efficiency, and in fact such assemblies have stunningly bad efficiencies. The problem is that the second TEC has to suck up all the heat from the first. So if you use one TEC to produce 5 watts of cooling (at a very low temperature), it will produce 50 watts of heat on the hot side. The second layer will need to accept 50 watts and (at 10% efficiency) will dissipate 500 watts on its hot side. Total efficiency will only be 1%. You don't need very cold temperatures - you need total energy removal.

**6. The input tube will be either 1/4" or 1/2**

Doesn't matter. Assuming 60W modules, you'd want about 70 or so TECs lined up with a single pipe running the length of the array. Water would fill the pipe and then be cooled for 90 seconds, then emptied quickly. Assuming the TECs measure about 2" x 2", the length of the pipe will need to be about 140 inches, or 12 feet or so. To get the relatively small volume (1000 ml) you'd need about 1000/140, or 7 ml/inch of pipe, which indicates an extremely narrow pipe in the cooling area.

So, like I say, it can be done. It's up to you to determine if it's worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer.  Using the figures above could the waste heat be used to generate electricity ? If yes then how much would be generated? And how?  Thank you again.  Ben Hodges

Comment: @BenHodges - Well, sort of but not really. Wherever you have a temperature difference you have the potential to harvest energy, but the lower the difference the lower the efficiency. A thermal engine will have a best-case efficiency equal to the temperature difference divided by the hot side temp in absolute measure. So, for a TEC with a 35 C hot side and a 15 degree ambient, difference is 20 K and ambient is (273 + 35) K, or 308 K. Maximum possible efficiency is then 20/308, or about 6%. And that's max. TECs run backwards are typically 1% or less.

Answer (score 0):

The specific heat capacity of water is such that it takes 4.2 joules of heat (or cooling) to raise (or lower) 1 gram of water 1°C.  Each ml of water is 1 gram.  So your 1000 ml of water is 1000 grams. You wish to go from 13°C to 5°C. That is a temperature change of 8°C. So 4.2 j per °C per gram * 1000 grams * 8°C = 33,600 j.

A Joule is equivalent to one watt-second. You wish to accomplish the temperature change in 90 seconds. So 33,600 j / 90 seconds = 373 watts. And you should assume about 50% inefficiency due to poor thermal coupling of the water to the Peltier surface. That takes you to about 750 watts of cooling. You can cascade Peltier coolers to obtain sufficient cooling.

The coefficient of performance of a Peltier device ranges between 0.4 to 0.7. Your power supply for the Peltier coolers will therefore need to supply between 1075 watts to 1875 watts.

You will need to take care to remove the heat from the Peltier cooler and keep it away from the water stream. This is typically done with heatsinks and fans. This system needs to shed 325 to 1125 watts of heat.